# How to use a dynamic background image URL with Tailwind CSS and React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

In React, I'm unable to use a URL string in my Tailwind background image class:

1: Not working, getting error "can't resolve ${link}"

```
const link = "https://cdn.test.net/test.jpg";

<div className={`px-4 py-1 h-[22rem] lg:h-[28vw] bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('${link}')]`}></div
```

2: Working, but I need to use a variable inside my `bg-` class.

```js
const link = "bg-[url('https://cdn.test.net/test.jpg')]";

<div className={`px-4 py-1 h-[22rem] lg:h-[28vw] bg-cover bg-center ${link}`}></div>
```

I still need to be able to use `${link}` inside `bg-[url('${link}')]`.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file generated by Tailwind will only include classes that it recognizes when it scans your code, which means that dynamically generated classes (e.g. `bg-[url('${link}')]`) will not be included.

If you only have a few different background images, you could add them to your `tailwind.config.js` and switch between them:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'first': "url('/img/first.jpg')",
        'second': "url('/img/second.jpg')",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div className={`bg-cover bg-center ${useFirst ? 'bg-first' : 'bg-second'}`}></div>
```

This would work, as long as you use the full utility class name, e.g. `bg-first`, in the code for Tailwind to find and include in the generated CSS.

If you need to reference completely arbitrary URL values, you can always use a `style` attribute instead of Tailwind classes. For example:

```
<div className="bg-cover bg-center" style={{backgroundImage: `url('${link}')`}}></div>
```

Comment: well but i need to pass link from an array that have objects for example: ```const imgobj = [
  { link: "https://cdn.test.test/124.jpg", name: "EVENT" },

  { link: "https://cdn.test.test/123.jpg", name: "TEST" }
]```

Comment: In that case, using the style attribute method above should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAKlu.png)

The given example should be working fine.
Working fine for me.

Comment: You should include your code answer as code text instead of attaching an image of the code.